# Jpos Generic Packager XML

Tags: iso, jpos

Im currently working with Jpos and created an xml for a process that has the description
ASCII/Packed Maps/Unpacked Numerics/ Var Len
I The xml works correctly with this process. I now want to make a second one for a process that rather than Unpacked Numerics it uses packed Numerics but im not sure what jpos classes would do this.
Iv tried changing all the IFA_Numerics to IFB_numerics and IFA_LLNUM to IFB_LLNUM but that didnt work

What classes represent packed numerics???

Answer (score 0):

So after looking through the process some more i found that it wants the length displayed not in binary so i needed to use the IFB_LLHNUM to indicate the datatype of the length